# WebBrowser do delphi

Tags: delphi

Há como melhorar o `WebBrowser` do Delphi? No formato atual ele não suporta páginas mais sofisticadas como a consulta pública do Pje tjmg.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei não tem como realizar melhorias nele... 
Uma boa alternativa é utilizar o Chromium [CEF4Delhpi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) 
ele é um projeto OpenSource da google e é um browser muito bom.

O Chromium funciona bem no Delphi 7 e nas novas versões RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo (Só testei até essa versão)

Obs.: Nos RAD Studio não consegui fazer funcionar no modelo de projeto Firemoney (FMX)

Comment: Já baixei e instalei no Delphi 7, mas não funciona nem pro cassete, sempre dá erros no momento da compilação, nem os exemplos funcionam...

Comment: Que estranho, você deve ter feito alguma coisinha errada, você procurou algum tutorial? Quando utilizei pela primeira vez, se não me engano, segui este tutorial [link](https://delphimaniaco.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/utilizando-o-navegador-chrome-no-delphi/). Não pode esquecer também que você deve por alguns arquivos do Chromium na mesma pasta do seu EXE para que o mesmo funcione.